# Searching for a string containing literal brackets with a Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

```
Date = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ("DateCreated:", "] [TotalTime:"), find_all(Text("Exam"))[0].value).group(1)
```

I am getting an error "unexpected end of regular expression". My guess is it is not accepting "] [" section in code.

Comment: Please consider simplifying your problem when asking a question, as given in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For instance, you could have a regex that *only* searched for the string `] [`; if that still caused the problem, there'd be a lot less guesswork (and the question would be much easier to read).

Comment: ...similarly, you're depending on variables (like `Text`) that your code doesn't define, meaning folks can't just copy-and-paste to see the problem for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.escape()` to escape a string such that it can be used as a literal in a regular expression.

Observe:

#### With contents escaped

```
>>> re.search(re.escape('] ['), 'foo ] [ bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105a956b0>
```

#### Without contents escaped

```
>>> re.search('] [', 'foo ] [ bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

#### Escaping Only Literal Components

In your immediate case, of course, you want to escape only the two literal strings you're searching between:

```
re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (re.escape("DateCreated:"),
                        re.escape("] [TotalTime:")),
          "DateCreated: yadda yadda ] [TotalTime: meh")
```

...by the way, notice how much easier proper indentation makes readability? You might think about doing that yourself in the future, or using an editor (such as emacs) which will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters should be escaped when using within regex pattern:

**1)** in a direct way:

```
Date = re.search(r'%s(.*)%s' % ("DateCreated:", "\] \[TotalTime:"), 'DateCreated: 04-01-2017 ] [TotalTime: 2')
print(Date.group(1))  # 04-01-2017
```

**2)** OR by using `re.escape()` function(which is preferable):

```
Date = re.search(r'%s(.*)%s' % (re.escape("DateCreated:"), re.escape("] [TotalTime:")), 'DateCreated: 04-01-2017 ] [TotalTime: 2')
print(Date.group(1)) # 04-01-2017
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape